# Struggling to return custom field in woocommerce shop subcategories

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to echo a custom field 'course_short_desc' underneath the title of each woocommerce subcategory on the parent category page (which lists all the shop subcategories).

Have spent a whole day on this without success. The closest I have got is the following code...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'display_short_course_info', 35 );  

function display_short_course_info() {
    $term_object = get_queried_object();
    echo the_field('course_short_desc', 'product_cat_'.$term_object->term_id);
}
```

This code does echo out 'course_short_desc' but for the parent category, not the shop subcategory itself. Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass the **$term_object** in de **the_field()** function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'display_short_course_info', 35 );
function display_short_course_info() {
    $term = get_queried_object();
    the_field('course_short_desc', $term);
}
```

also **the_field()** function already echo's the field.
this function is the same as echo **get_field()**.